# bootstrap form not working. receiving blank form

Tags: php, jquery, forms

i used bootstrap form but unable to send data from the form pleas can any body help me with this i tried a lot now i am `receiving only blank mail` like 
Name:

Email:

Subject:

Message:

with the hosting email id like `xxxx@hostmonster.com` how do i change the receiving from "to the sender id" below is my code

```
<form id="main-contact-form" class="contact-form" name="contact-form" method="post" action="http://smalldesigncompany.com/client/form-sending/sendemail.php" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="name" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="email" name="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <input type="text" name="subject" class="form-control" placeholder="Subject" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <textarea name="message" class="form-control" rows="8" placeholder="Message" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Send Message</button>
</form>
```

**my jquery:**

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form').serialize();
form.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function () {
            form.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn());
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();

    });
});
```

**my php:**

```
<?php 
header('Content-type: '); 
$status = array( 
    'type'=>'success', 
    'message'=>'Thank you for contact us. As early as possible  we will contact you ' 
); 

$name = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['name']));  
$email = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['email']));  
$subject = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['subject']));  
$message = @trim(stripslashes($_POST['message']));  

$email_from = $email; 
$email_to = 'sales.mtc@outlook.com'; 

$body = 'Name: ' . $name . "\n\n" . 'Email: ' . $email . "\n\n" . 'Subject: ' . $subject . "\n\n" . 'Message: ' . $message; 

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, 'From: <'.$email_from.'>'); 

echo json_encode($status); 
die; 
?>
```

Comment: Do stop using the `@` to ignore errors. If you got errors FIX 'EM

Comment: You need to serialize the form inside jquery's submit function. Also try alerting it (or some individual input values) and see if there is anything assigned to the variable.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add header. May be your "\n\n" creating problem.

```
$header = "From: noreply@example.com\r\n"; 
$header.= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n"; 
$header.= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1\r\n"; 
$header.= "X-Priority: 1\r\n"; 

$success = @mail($email_to, $subject, $body, $header);
```

Comment: where should i add this?

Comment: I have edited my answer. Above the "$success" line put code of header and include that variable as shown in answer.

Comment: No sir, No luck with this also

Comment: is that possible this error may be due to some server issue like the hosting provider issue?

Comment: Any special reason to use ajax? Submitting form is not fine?

Comment: Yes, submit form to the page where your php code is written like mail.php. In this page get all form data using $_POST like $_POST['name'] or $_POST['email'] and use these values to send email.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your javascript - your jQuery.ajax doesn't actually contain any data!

As per jQuery docs (http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> ***data***
>   Type: PlainObject or String or Array
>   Data to be sent to the server. It is converted to a query string, if not already a string. It's appended to the url for GET-requests. See processData option to prevent this automatic processing. Object must be Key/Value pairs. If value is an Array, jQuery serializes multiple values with same key based on the value of the traditional setting (described below).

You can use jquery.serialize (https://api.jquery.com/serialize/) on your inputs to create the required data string to pass through.

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the `data` you're sending as `JQuery` && `PHP` won't know what values you're posting. Take a look at the Jquery Docs on Data ([LINK](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/))

**Modified Code:**

```
var form = $('#main-contact-form').serialize();
form.submit(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var form_status = $('<div class="form_status"></div>');
    $.ajax({
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: "json",
        data: {
            name: $('input[name="name"]').val(),
            email: $('input[name="email"]').val(),
            subject: $('input[name="subject"]').val(),
            message: $('textarea[name="message"]').val(),
        },
        beforeSend: function () {
            form.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn());
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Js would be like this,

```
$('#main-contact-form').on('submit', function (event) {
    form = $(this);
    var formData = form.serialize();
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        url: form.attr('action'),
        type: 'POST',
        data: formData,
        beforeSend: function () {
            form.prepend(form_status.html('<p><i class="fa fa-spinner fa-spin"></i> Email is sending...</p>').fadeIn());
        }
    }).done(function (data) {
        form_status.html('<p class="text-success">' + data.message + '</p>').delay(3000).fadeOut();

    });
});
```

and it will work perfectly.